# Conditional response type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a function that will return me a `Response<T>` when I provide a value on its argument, and `Response<string>` when I don't. The return type that I have works for me, the issue is I'm getting errors on both response statements saying I'm not returning the correct type.

```
interface ResponseOverride<Value> {
  value?: Value;
  onChange?(): void;
}

interface Response<T> {
  value: T;
  onChange(): void;
}

function getResponse<T, K extends ResponseOverride<T>>({
  value: overrideValue,
  ...overrides
}: K): K extends {value: T} ? Response<T> : Response<string> {
  const defaults = {
    onChange:() => {},
  };

  if (overrideValue !== undefined) {
    return {...defaults, ...overrides, value: overrideValue};
  }

  return {...defaults, ...overrides, value: ''};
}
```

How can I achieve this without having to do something like `return {...} as any;`?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=24&pc=2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoQM4AcD2IMQDyAbtFMACYQA8AanADYCuEAfMgN4CwAUMssUYsA-AC5k9ZhADcvfngDCACzggA5hGEAKAJTjiOSrJ4BfXr1CRYiFOmx4CAQWoAVdtz4ChEcS+PyQZVUNXX1DCmMzHl4YJhAEMGA8ZA0wO1x8GhcAGmQAaWQIAA9IEAoMNEwMghIySizWVi0PfkEpcRxSKHIqSRZsuWQAOhHOuqoMXhNxPL18wpKIMoqONpZfE2RhSvtM5zdkcXSHCGcMMHJ1d0GEBzBkKngmBjAKgF5OQYCg9R9kXWQb3cJgGnhMxkGwBg-zG3XqfRQAEI3h84o9QBAKDpPp5+FAIGAmFAQJwRkNHnBnq9cmTYT1MLk1n86fDvODBlFBvjCcTSSMKVSMDTRl16UKvO1kAByKXs0xAA)

Comment: The short answer is that the compiler will not be able to verify that a particular return value will be assignable to a conditional type that depends on a currently-unspecified type parameter, and you will need to use either type assertions or the equivalent to proceed.  That said, it looks like you're just trying to get a reasonable typing for `Object.assign()`/spread like [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21316#issuecomment-359574388).

Answer (score 2):

Before we get started, the `T` type parameter in your code example is always inferred as `unknown` because there is nothing for it to be inferred from.  So I will remove it and replace it with `unknown`.  Secondly, the `K` type parameter is not being used as a key type (`K extends keyof ...`) so the use of the `K` name is not conventional.  Instead I'll just use `T`.

---

The issue is that inside the implementation of `getResponse()`, the generic type parameter `T` is not specified, and the compiler cannot currently verify that a value is assignable to a conditional type that depends on an unspecified type parameter.  The difficulty in getting generic conditional typed function return values to type check is [an open issue (see microsoft/TypeScript#33912)](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912).  For now, there are only workarounds, like [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) and the moral equivalent, a single call-signature [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads).

For type assertions, there is likely something less unsafe than `any`, but nothing easy to write out.

For the overload, you could do it like this:

```
// call signature
function getReponse<T extends ResponseOverride<unknown>>({
  value: overrideValue,
  ...overrides
}: T): T extends { value: unknown } ? Response<T["value"]> : Response<string>;

// implementation
function getReponse(
  { value: overrideValue, ...overrides }: ResponseOverride<unknown>
): Response<unknown> {
  if (overrideValue !== undefined) {
    return { ...defaults, ...overrides, value: overrideValue };
  }

  return { ...defaults, ...overrides, value: '' };
}
```

So this works well enough, but of course if you were to mess up the return value the compiler will probably not catch it; a single call-signature overload is lax in a similar way as a type assertion (which is why I call it the "moral equivalent").

---

Looking at your code, though, I see that what you're doing is mostly just using the [object spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals), which is essentially the same as using [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).  For generic types, the TypeScript compiler just produces an [intersection type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) which is not accurate when properties get overriden.

Since you're using conditional types anyway, you might want to use a type like `Spread<L, R>` (mentioned in [a GitHub issue comment by @ahejlsberg](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21316#issuecomment-359574388)) and define a function called `spread()` which uses it.  The unsafe assertion/overload could be contained inside `spread()`, and you can write `getResponse()` with this function and get your output types for free.

Here's a definition of `Spread`:

```
// Optional keys in T
type OptionalKeys<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?: {} extends Pick<T, K> ? K : never }[keyof T];

// Common properties from L and R with undefined in R[K] replaced by type in L[K]
type SpreadProperties<L, R, K extends keyof L & keyof R> =
  { [P in K]: L[P] | Exclude<R[P], undefined> };

// Type of { ...L, ...R }
type Spread<L, R> = (
  // Properties in L that don't exist in R
  & Pick<L, Exclude<keyof L, keyof R>>
  // Properties in R with types that exclude undefined
  & Pick<R, Exclude<keyof R, OptionalKeys<R>>>
  // Properties in R, with types that include undefined, that don't exist in L
  & Pick<R, Exclude<OptionalKeys<R>, keyof L>>
  // Properties in R, with types that include undefined, that exist in L
  & SpreadProperties<L, R, OptionalKeys<R> & keyof L>
) extends infer T ? { [K in keyof T]: T[K] } : never;

function spread<T>(t: T): T;
function spread<T, U>(t: T, u: U): Spread<T, U>;
function spread<T, U, V>(t: T, u: U, v: V): Spread<Spread<T, U>, V>;
function spread<T, U, V, W>(t: T, u: U, v: V, w: W): Spread<Spread<Spread<T, U>, V>, W>;
function spread(t: any, ...rest: any[]) {
  return Object.assign({}, t, ...rest);
}
```

And here's how I'd write `getResponse()`:

```
function getResponse<T extends { value?: unknown, onChange?(): void }>(r: T) {
  return spread({ onChange: () => { }, value: "" }, r);
}
```

And here are the returned types:

```
const blankResponse = getResponse({});
// const blankResponse: {  onChange: () => void;  value: string; }

const valueResponse = getResponse({ value: 123 });
// const valueResponse: { onChange: () => void; value: number; }

const eitherOrResponse = getResponse(Math.random() < 0.5 ? {} : { value: 123 });
// const eitherOrResponse: { onChange: () => void; value: string | number; }

const overrideOnChange = getResponse({ onChange() { return 123; } })
// const overrideOnChange: {  value: string;  onChange: () => number;  }
```

Seems good to me.

---

Okay, hope one of those ideas gives you some way forward.  Good luck!

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAsAFBJKiSwLIDyATgJYDmdoGeRJJzALhDQGaUkAJWgwA9sCgQqAN170AJhAA8AFQB8bYhxIzMAVwgB+AFxJVAbnY6kEgMIALEMAbGAFAEozMsXQVXtEgBfdmtOYB5+QRFYCSk1TQJAjj0MQzNLMI57JxcIT29ffyyQwiy+fWB4LjoJJFcuEXFJFVUkCAAPHmAFKGFROOk5GkUVSoBrYDEAd2B1dTckmyRU9Nth0YA1AwgAGiySADpjsQ2-aBKMr3N2rogevtwVnbMJqdmkIKQjftiWtQA2gAiVYQIEAXU0ZhizXiUC49Bc6gCOgqVRqdQaTUGbgOeGeaQgZlO8nO20JuyQx0OJJG5z6QWhAxaslJSmUbxmcyy1xhgw5wEmXMSePgcS4SCUAn0GC4fQAvFpliQcs5XGZPEh5YlPvtksEAni6HwkG5aVsdkgAITyxWVKXMCAKDxK5U0CBcfQ0YD46lSkAyuWU6nm+mU0HEs5KcmGT4omylPHuz3e33Hf2BqDBk5R6Dhl5IADkhbjJSIWTFkglACMMM5xnyWlr6h7sS1FkEPBYkAB6Hu-WEqeGIhjqCvigmGRtSZtYiCDxaTolIACMACYAMyfLu9-vTlTAfRgau8MfJSvw9p0LgOXi0fez1vznEAWRAN8ONGcCjEYE1yiQAAGQ4AFZvjwL4zCeCNV03bduz7Ad+WHZhRyQAAfJD-kPY9T3HKt1jZaRgEcNVkEVOcFyeVU8k1J5ky9H11w3bsvk7EhEP3ZQUKRaxE20MhREEABlGB3RABRXQ4-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-S1eMzX1EZ7a1vmPFdY5-XuaNykTcq3rsud63Rbth13qdy33eJr3kc26GJPZ6aDcp4Rlb0iQQ41hHNvpgrtZIF1Oncw2+F4G4fnMyzrMj2KMiaz4kFC8LeG+jg0WqfSkFgcaEjcLgrgyeMSBn+T57EmGFH8pAAFUFhX8wXrMA-rhLvfVEpI-15yypZ7qBfd-3g-KU2Y+MjPw-wzMTZL471hlfN+4ckCf3vpvOeL9YY31-uAykAB1L+p8qrnz-ggsqZhEGAMXiAkBcCj4fzAcgyBj8t4wIUMvMwzhlLZk-NAE+tCATghdEsGwDFUxUGrAAKwgNUQ4IAoBQEYMADsTt6HunhF2MsZRkhQMxE+P48Q2jt2Wo8JcLlOSzEpDRVwRgCgrCKJ8BYNArhSQ4Jwn0lDFx6OXJqbU+Igj5kJGYIEQJdQtRkckfiOgLw1jrIKB8FElFUU7PfRC-ikC1nrPuKCKoSK5HVKaF0jifB+G7EuMwPEGCsXLOeCcoJgktkaMyKQi4YLMXglkSJhSdhxPxHYjUqTNDpP8Fk0gR4Tw0DyXIvxE4IAVTvDQYpc5lH5DfB+L8PRfz-iAqBcCuBIL4kqXBcJNT+xRMGTeYZDTqKJLIs0rUrSijdhgjkjCnTcI9Ihn0jgUTQxKCoAcvIj5SnjNsS81wdEWoekYrBFio9OwbKQA83MzzSJ5HiR0nJmSmkpOOVc7pmTfG3KCEAA)